# iOS App Clip: How Can I create profile for it?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, profile, apple-appclips

I have create app clip in an iOS project, archive success, but in this step, I cannot select profile of clip, How to solve it?

[image]

Click down load profile will show as bellow: "No Eligible Profiles"

[image: enter image no here]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same account you used to create bundle ID.
(you need a paid developer Account to do this)

If you still get the error create a new Bundle Id.

Comment: I have already distribute it success with a simple app with clip in it to apple store , I can see it in ituneconnect. Just cannot distribute may current project which have much of code.

Comment: Try checking if your Product Bundle Identifier is correct.                           
                                                                                                                   
  Bundle Identifier in Target -> Build Settings -> Product Bundle Identifier

Comment: Same as what I success dristribute

Comment: Bundle I’d incorrect will not let me archive success

Comment: In Target -> General -> Signing, Try manually setting the Provisioning Profiles (turning off 'Automatically manage signing' and set them myself).  Sometimes the Product Bundle Identifier might be set wrong in Xcode, which might cause a mismatch with your Provisioning Profile.

Comment: By default, the Debug configuration is used for running on the Simulator while the Release is for Archives. I recommend looking at your Schemes.

Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme...

Comment: Debug configuration will not allowed me to archive success.